# Why does "Coin change" problem make no output in top down recursive function without Dp?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Top-down Recursive function to find minimum coin.

```
#define INF 1000000
int coin[5] ={100,20,10,5,1};
int bill(int x)
{
    if(x==0)
           return 0;
    if(x<0)
           return INF;
    int ans = INF;
    for(auto q:coin)
           ans =min(ans,bill(x-q)+1);
    return ans;
          
}
```

when value of x is greater than 60, I have found nothing in output like program is going into infinite loop. what is the real matter behind this? I don't see no cycle here because  every sub-problem will always reach the base case.

```
input: x=100
expected output : 1

0utput: (not terminated ... ... loading..)
```

I've tried to realize the main cause behind this .

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand at all what you are trying to ask. There is no output in the shown code. Also `INF` is not defined (it is not standard) and an `int` can not hold an infinity value. Please show a complete [mre] including the output you get and the output you expected and then explain what you are confused about.

Comment: Side note  : returning "special" return values is not recommended. Either throw an exception if pre/post conditions cannot be met or return `std::optional<int>`  (or C++23's [std::expected])https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected)).

Comment: There is no infinite loop. You are just not giving the program enough time to complete. Consider how the number of `bill` calls (and with it the program runtime) will increase when `x` increases with your algorithm. Also, consider how deep the recursion will be and check that it won't exceed your stack size. It would be better to use an iterative approach instead of a recursive one in order to avoid exceeding the stack limit.

Comment: *"I don't see no cycle here because"*-- Because you are looking at this theoretically? It's rather simple to switch to a practical perspective. Just add some output to track your function calls, something like `std::cerr << "called bill() with x = " << x << "\n";` at the beginning of `bill()` (right before `if(x==0)`). Is there a cycle? What are the values of `x` in the cycle?

Comment: Use memoization, otherwise it will be too expensive and time consuming to complete your program, could also result in stack overflow. Neetcode has solved this program using memoization

Answer (score 2):

The running time of your algorithm is unfortunately *exponential*, which is impractical to compute for large values of x, in a *you-will-not-live-that-long* kind of way.  On my computer, it takes about 1.35 times as long to calculate `bill(x+1)` as it does to compute `bill(x)`.

That means that although you could compute `bill(60)` in less than a minute, you could expect `bill(100)` to **take about 10^31 years**.

You are critically missing [**memoization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) in your implementation, where you would remember previously calculated values of `bill(x)` in a cache rather than computing them entirely from scratch each time the function needs to be evaluated.